# Angular : How to implement condtion based click event?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've a component in which there are two things let say 'order information' and 'datepicker'. By clicking on that component it'll show the information of the order.

What I want is that don't trigger the click event if user click on datepicker icon, so for this I'm trying to do this type of logic:

```
<app-order-info
  (click)="$event.target.classList.contains('icon-mydrpcalender') ? null : showOrdersinfo()"     
>
</app-order-info>
```

But this is only working in chrome but in other browsers like firefox and internet explorer, even when I click on the datepicker icon it's still firing the click event.

How to resolve this please.

Comment: Does it work if you move the logic into `showOrdersinfo` and return early?

Comment: No same issue only works in chrome but not in firefox and internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to resolve it with css `pointer-events: none` . If you don't want it triggered on that calendar icon

Answer (score 0):

I think also better to add all this code:

```
"$event.target.classList.contains('icon-mydrpcalender') ? null : showOrdersinfo()"
```

in function inside component.
Read something about it and try to setup it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to handle the `(click)` on individual elements in your component and emit a event from the component. Something like this:

```
@Component({
selector:'sample'
template: "<a (click)='emitThis($event)' >Emit</a>  <a>Do Not Emit</a>"
 })
 export class YourComponent { 
    @Output() eventEmitter: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    emitThis(evnt){
        this.eventEmitter.emit(evnt);
    }
}
```

Use it like `<sample (eventEmitter)='callSomeFunction(event)'></sample>`